# reduce ffmpeg execution time and check if there anything wrong in command

Tags: android, ffmpeg

i am using ffmpeg to create video from images and i have  2 image store in my sd card but when i am runing code it takes too long to execute or sometimes its shows only executing..my question is how to increase speed and check if there is anything wrong in my command

```
     String cmd[]={ "-r" ,"1/5", "-i", inputputimg, "-strict", 
  "experimental", "-vcodec" ,"libx264" ,"-preset" ,"ultrafast" ,"-crf" 
  ,"30",output};   

      String 
   inputputimg="/storage/emulated/0/FestiveApp/temp/img%02d.jpeg";



            public void ImageCommand(String command[])
{

    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity2.this);
    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e("ffmpeg","Exaction Start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                imageprogressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("ok",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                imageprogressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                imageprogressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("ffmpeg","Exaction Start");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        imageprogressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("ffmpeg",e.toString());
    }
}
```

i want video should takes some sec to edit and also i trying to merge to video but it also takes same things

Comment: this is working for me...but  i am not able to execute the 2 video merge command..one video has audio and one created by 2 images  the command is below..please or correct if there is any wrong

Comment: String [] merge2video={ "-i", input1 ,"-i", input2,"-filter_complex", "[0:v] [0:a:0] [1:v] [0:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]","-strict", "experimental", "-vcodec" ,"libx264" ,"-preset" ,"ultrafast" ,"-crf" ,"30", output};